# Is there any free-to-use scenario builder?

Tags: security, testing, formal-verification, compound-protocol

The [Compound Protocol](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol) has a collection of high-level integration tests, dubbed "scenarios":

https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/tree/v2.8.1/spec

Which look like this:

```
Test "Mint 1 cZRX"
    NewComptroller
    ListedCToken ZRX cZRX initialExchangeRate:1e9
    Prep Geoff Some ZRX cZRX
    Mint Geoff 50e18 cZRX
    Assert Equal (Erc20 cZRX TokenBalance Geoff) (Exactly 50e9)
    -- Assert Equal (CToken cZRX UnderlyingBalance Geoff) (Exactly 1.0e18)
```

These are built with [Certora](https://www.certora.com/), which bears a cost.

Is there any free tool that can do this or something alike?